# How do I modify node value while iterating with XPathNodeIterator?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpathdocument, xpathnodeiterator

I'm navigating XML document with XPathNodeIterator, and I want to change some nodes' values.
I can't figure out how :(

Here's the code I'm using:

```
XPathDocument docNav = new XPathDocument(path);

XPathNavigator nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
nav.MoveToRoot();

XPathNodeIterator itemsIterator = nav.Select("/foo/bar/item");
while (mediumsIterator.MoveNext())
{
    XPathNodeIterator subitemsIterator = itemsIterator.Current.Select("SubitemsList/name");
    while (subitemsIterator.MoveNext())
    {
        XPathNodeIterator nodesIterator = itemsIterator.Current.Select("Param");
        nodesIterator.MoveNext();
        String the_params = nodesIterator.Current.Value;

        // check if I need to modify nodesIterator.Current.Value
        // ...
        // ok I do - how?
    }
}
```

And the XML file sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar>
    <item>
      <Param />
      <SubitemsList>
        <name>name one</name>
        <name>name two</name>
        ...
      </SubitemsList>
    </item>
    ...
  </bar>
</foo>
```

Or maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: please don't put the tags in the title.  I've removed them for you.

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's not much effort to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way:

1. Replace `XPathDocument` with `XmlDocument`
2. When I get to the needed node

...

```
XmlNode node = ((IHasXmlNode)nodesIterator.Current).GetNode();
node.InnerText = "new text";
```